# Deploy jar Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment

i've not developed for a long time.

Now i'm starting developing again. I've built spring boot application, but unfortunately after "Maven:Install" in Intellij a copy the file to Tomcat 8, Tomcat don't deploy the app.

In server.xml i have autoDeploy="true"

The build section in pom.xml is:

```
<build>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Of course Tomcat works fine.

In catalina there is no info, that tomcat is trying to deploy - exactly nothing.

Could you support me, what i forgot?

Answer (score 0):

if you develop a spring boot application , you don't need to copy file to tomcat.
You have only to run the generated jar file with:

> 'java -jar jarFileName.jar'

and will start the application. The tomcat is included in the jar file

Comment: So i can put the jar file anywhere in server and just run it?

Comment: No. You don't need to copy the jar into the server. Only run the jar with `java -jar ...` command. that's enough.

Comment: For your other question regarding when you close the console, application will stop. this is true.
therefore, start the application with a batch / shell script

Answer (score 0):

TO be able to deploy your spring boot application as .war file to tomcat server you need the following prerequsites:

1. add spring-boot-maven plugin to your pom.xml

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${springboot.version}</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>repackage</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. You should make your SpringBootApplication extend SpringBootServletInitializer

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class YourSpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(YourSpringBootApplication .class, args);
       }

       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(YourSpringBootApplication .class);
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, one more question - even if i want to use build in Tomcat (Spring Boot) how should i run application and leave it running? If i will use "java -jar ...." when i close console, application will stop.